# customer id with email id sql?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I just want to fetch customer id with email as parameter from the mysql database. How can i hit the sql query to get the customer_id.

```
 $passphrase = "password";
 $salt = "SC";
 $password = md5($salt . $passphrase) . ":SC";

 $write->query("update customer_entity_varchar set value='$password' where entity_id=$customer_id and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='password_hash' and entity_type=1)");
```

This is the code which i been using to update password , I need dynamic customer id.

this is full code

```
<?php 
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();  
if($_POST && $_POST["email"])
    {


          $collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()      ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('myemail@domain.com') 
         ->addAttributeToSort('email', 'ASC');
          var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());
                         die();

                       $passphrase = "password";
                       $salt = "SC";
                       $password = md5($salt . $passphrase) . ":SC";

                       $write->query("update customer_entity_varchar set value='$password' where entity_id=$customer_id and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='password_hash' and entity_type=1)");


                      $send_data["success"]=true;
                      $send_data["message"]="Login Success";
                      $send_data["customer_id"]=$customer_id;

    }
    else
    {
            $send_data["success"]=false;
            $send_data["message"]="Enter both Email and Password";
    }
     Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($send_data["customer_id"]);
    echo json_encode($send_data);

    ?>
```

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer change this line  `->addAttributeToFilter('email',$_POST['email']) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code in magento

```
$collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('email',$_POST['email']) 
 ->addAttributeToSort('email', 'ASC');
 var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());
```

this will print following query

```
SELECT e.*, at_firstname.value AS firstname FROM customer_entity AS e INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_firstname ON (at_firstname.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_firstname.attribute_id = '5') WHERE (e.entity_type_id = '1') AND (at_firstname.value = 'sander') ORDER BY e.email ASC
```

Comment: and where i have to pass customer email ?

Comment: In above code you will get Email for all customer in foreach loop or you want to filter on email bases ?

Comment: yes i want to filter with email , i want 1 record base on email , which should return customer_id.

Comment: please look at my updated collection

Comment: earlier it was returning a query  , but now its been throwing 500 in ajax

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: returning same 500

Comment: instead ajax try with browser and check what is the error

Comment: see my updated ques

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer

Comment: any update on this??

Answer (score 0):

You can change your password in following way. It is fetching dynamic customer id on the basis of customer email Id.

```
$email = $_POST["email"]; //Customer email id
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $passphrase = "123456";
        $salt = "SC";
        $password = md5($salt . $passphrase) . ":SC";
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $query = "update customer_entity_varchar set value='" . $password . "' where entity_id=" . $customer->getId() . " and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='password_hash' and entity_type_id=1)";
        $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $connection->query($query);
```